# In jupyter notebook how to bring tkinter.filedialog window to the top of all windows?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm running the following in jupyter notebook using python 3:

```py
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
%gui tk
my_file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

When I run it the tkinter window launches somewhere behind the browser. How can I raise it to the top?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've tested the following code snippet in several jupyter notebooks and it seems to work:

```
from tkinter import*
# Create Tk root
root = Tk()
# Hide the main window
root.withdraw()
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)

from tkinter import filedialog
infiles = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True)

%gui tk
```

So that's what I have so far but I'll keep working on it. I think that there may be some JavaScript solutions out there.

Comment: I get a runtime warning when I run this code in JupyterLab (v3.1.14 server  with Jupyter_client v6.1.1.12)    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PyQt5Options\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\eventloops.py:256: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Kernel.do_one_iteration' was never awaited
  self.func()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Answer (score 1):

It seems the response to this answer changes depending on the IDE/kernel you're using.  I had a solution that worked in a Jupyter Notebook (see Solution A below) using the default kernel.  Then I had issues with that when I opened the same code in Jupyter Labs with xpython (xeus-python) (see Solution B below).  Someone may be able to better comment on why the IDE/kernel has different results.

Note that the below is for selecting a directory, but works the same as for a specific file.

Solution A:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    
    file_path = askdirectory(parent=root)

    root.destroy()
```

Solution B:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes('-topmost',True)
    root.iconify()
    
    file_path = askdirectory(parent=root)

    root.destroy()
```

Solution B came from https://github.com/python-eel/Eel/issues/395