# Select Specific Sheet from Python Imported Excel File

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

The following code requests the user to select an excel file they'd like to import as a pandas data frame; however, it doesn't provide the ability to select which sheet (if multiple exist):

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

x = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = 1)
x
```

Conditions to include in new solution:

- If only one sheet exists, automatically select and upload to pandas data frame
- If multiple sheets exists, allow user to choose through a dialog box which sheet they'd like to import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution offered by @GordonAitchJay, and implementation with Tkinter, is excellent. Definitely the way to go, if you're running the script directly with Python or in an IDE like Spyder.

However, the OP is working in Jupyter and it turns out that Jupyter and Tkinter do not get along very well. The OP expressed difficulties, and while I do get it to work at first, if I push the code for performance, I'm also noticing serious lags and hiccups. This being the case, I thought I would just add a way to make the interaction work smoothly in Jupyter by using the [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) framework.

```
# Jupyter notebook

import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import clear_output
from ipyfilechooser import FileChooser
from ipywidgets import interact
from pathlib import Path

# get home dir of user
home = str(Path.home()) 

# initialize a dict for the excel file; this removes the need to set global values
dict_file = {}

# change to simply `home` if you want users to navigate through diff dirs
fc = FileChooser(f'{home}/excel') 

# same here
fc.sandbox_path = f'{home}/excel'

# limit file extensions to '.xls, .xlsb, .xlsm, .xlsx'
fc.filter_pattern = ['*.xls*']
fc.title = '<b>Select Excel file</b>'
display(fc)

# create empty dropdown for sheet names
dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=[''], value='', description='Sheets:', disabled=False)

# create output frame for the df
out = widgets.Output(layout=widgets.Layout(display='flex', flex_flow='column', align_items='flex-start', width='100%'))

# callback func for FileChooser
def get_sheets(chooser): 

    # (re)populate dict
    dict_file.clear() 
    dict_file['file'] = pd.ExcelFile(fc.value)
    sheet_names = dict_file['file'].sheet_names
    
    # only 1 sheet, we'll print this one immediate (further below)
    if len(sheet_names) == 1:
        
        # set value of the dropdown to this sheet
        dropdown.options = sheet_names
        dropdown.value = sheet_names[0]
        
        # disable the dropdown; so it's just showing the selection to the user
        dropdown.disabled = True
    else:
        
        # append empty string and set this as default; this way the user must always make a deliberate choice
        sheet_names.append('')
        dropdown.options = sheet_names
        dropdown.value = sheet_names[-1]
        
        # allow selection by user
        dropdown.disabled = False
    return

# bind FileChooser to callback
fc.register_callback(get_sheets)

# prompt on selection sheet
def show_df(sheet):
    if sheet == '':
        if out != None:
            # clear previous df, when user selects a new wb
            out.clear_output()
    else:
        # clear previous output 'out' frame before displaying new df, else they'll get stacked
        out.clear_output()
        with out:
            df = dict_file['file'].parse(sheet_name=sheet)
            if len(df) == 0:
                # if sheet is empty, let the user know
                display('empty sheet')
            else:
                display(df)
    return

# func show_df is called with input of widget as param on selection sheet
interact(show_df, sheet=dropdown)

# display 'out' (with df)
display(out)
```

Snippet of interaction in notebook:

[image: nb interaction df from excel file]

Comment: Nice. `ipywidgets` is clearly the way to go!

Comment: I am getting the following error, @ouroboros1 .  ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipyfilechooser'```.  Any tips?

Comment: You can install it via pip: `pip install ipyfilechooser`

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that? @ouroboros1

Comment: Is it just it's own cell in the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Should probably work just to open `command prompt` (if you're on Windows; just start typing it in the search box) and then type the command I've mentioned above. Might need to refresh your jupyter env. Otherwise, if you google `pip install package` or adding `jupyter`, your first hits will contain lots of documentation of methods that might apply to your situation. Generally, a good idea to google some resources on how to install packages, because you'll be needing to do it often enough with python.

Answer (score 2):

If that's all you need `tkinter` for, this will do.

It shows a simple combobox with the sheetnames. In this case, the first sheetname is named *Orders*.

As soon as you select an item, the window closes and it parses that sheet.

[image: Tkinter combobox]

```py
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
# limit user input to Excel file (or path == '' in case of "Cancel")
path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [('Excel files', '*.xls*')])

# if user didn't cancel, continue
if path != '':
    # Get the sheetnames first without parsing all the sheets
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(path)
    sheet_names = excel_file.sheet_names
    sheet_name = None
    
    if len(sheet_names) == 1:
        sheet_name = sheet_names[0]
    elif len(sheet_names) > 1:
        # Show the window again
        root.deiconify()
        root.minsize(280, 30)
        root.title('Select sheet to open')
        
        # Create a combobox with the sheetnames as options to select
        combotext = tk.StringVar(value=sheet_names[0])
        box = ttk.Combobox(root, 
                           textvariable=combotext, 
                           values=sheet_names, 
                           state='readonly')
        box.pack()
        
        # This function gets called when you select an item in the combobox
        def callback_function(event):
            # Mark sheet_name as global so it doesn't just make a new local variable
            global sheet_name
            sheet_name = combotext.get()
            
            # Close tkinter so Python can continue execution after root.mainloop()
            root.destroy()
        
        root.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', callback_function)
        root.mainloop()
    
    # Finally, parse the selected sheet
    # This is equivalent to pd.read_excel
    df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that the dialog box does not disappear after running the code.  It continues to stay and buffers until I force quit it, resulting in my kernel restarting.  Is there a way around this? @GordonAitchJay

Comment: Try adding `root` as the first argument to `ttk.Combobox`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Minor suggestion for improvement. If you use `path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [('Excel files', '*.xls*')])`, you limit possible user input to Excel files: i.e. the user will only be able to see, and select `.xls, .xlsx, .xlsb, .xlsm`. Even then, you do well to place the entire code starting from `excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(path)` inside an `if-statement` to handle a user clicking `Cancel`, which will lead to `path == ''`. So, you could simply use: `if path != '':`.

Comment: Good ideas! You can edit my answer if you like. Cheers

Comment: No dice, unfortunately.  I've tried on both windows and Mac @GordonAitchJay

Comment: Damn, I dunno man. It works fine on my Windows 10 machine, both when run in Spyder and as a standalone script. I don't use Jupyter, but maybe raise an issue on their issues tracker? https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues

Comment: Does it work if you run the script directly with Python?

Comment: Would it be worthwhile to post a new question with this updated code and use the Jupyter tag? @GordonAitchJay

Comment: Directly with Python works fine. As is, it got stuck in Jupyter here too. The problem is apparently with `root.withdraw()`. If I comment it out, it also just works fine, but you will get the empty root window behind the filedialog. But we can avoid this. From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307442/in-jupyter-notebook-how-to-bring-tkinter-filedialog-window-to-the-top-of-all-win) I've copied `root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)`. When I add this after `root.withdraw()`, it works like a charm. I would tell you why, but then I don't know... But it does :).

Comment: @ouroboros1 interesting! Feel free to edit my answer with that. Cheers

Comment: @HelpMeCode You can do that if you like. Though I think it's really more of a Jupyter bug which should be brought to their attention and fixed.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay do I just paste the code in there and describe the apparent issue?  I've never done this before.

Comment: @ouroboros1 I pasted this code right below line 5 and still seem to have that same issue :-( on both windows and Mac.  Am I inserting it at the correct location?

Comment: Should be line immediately after `root.withdraw()`. Doesn't work? Have you tried the (less ideal) option of not inserting the line and just commenting out `root.withdraw()`. Does that work? For me it does, but with the root window in background. I found some info (but a bit sketchy) on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644054/what-does-the-tk-call-function-do-in-python-tkinter) and [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/wm.html). I'm also on Windows 10 here btw.

Comment: Silly. Actually, it does *run* here in the original version on Jupyter. It's just that it opens the file dialog *behind* the browser, so I didn't see it, and if I then interrupt the kernel, it is of course gone again. So, this is what the `root.call()` does: it is pushing the window to the front. @HelpMeCode, when you try with `root.call()`, be sure first to restart your kernel. You cannot rerun the cell, while it's still pending (and in this case, the window might actually be open in the background). It's pending when in the left margin, you see `In [*]:` rather than `In [ ]:`.

Comment: yes, and when I make a selection from the dialog box, and select a sheet (if more than one exists), the ```button``` that allowed me to select the sheet just doesn't go away.  When I put my cursor on it, it just gives the buffering sign.  I then have to use task manager to force quite Python and the kernel interrupts.  The only issue is that this secondary window (what I'm calling a button) does not effectively close after choosing the needed worksheet. @ouroboros1